# Split the strings in two parts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I am writing the code as I want to create the variable to get the strings that will converts the time from 24 hours to 12 hours. Then I want to split the strings to get the minute after the `:`.

Example:

When my strings shows as:

```
22:30
22:30
22:40
23:05
23:00
23:00
23:00
```

Output:

```
10:30 PM
10:30 PM
10:40 PM
11:05 PM
11:00 PM
11:00 PM
11:00 PM
```

So when I try this:

```
stop_time = str(stop_date[1])

converts_time = time.strptime(stop_time, "%H:%M")
converts_time = time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + str(":") + str(stop_time.split(":")) + time.strftime("%p")
```

I will get this:

```
10:['22', '30'] PM
10:['22', '30'] PM
10:['22', '40'] PM
10:['23', '05'] PM
10:['23', '00'] PM
10:['23', '00'] PM
10:['23', '00'] PM
```

I want to use the lstrip method to remove the `0` when my current time show in PM and I don't wish to use the lstrip when my current time show in AM. As you can see that I am using stop_time.split method, I want to converts the hours from 24 to 12 hours then I want to split the strings after the `:` to get the minute for each string to make it show like: 10:30 PM, 10:40 PM...etc so I can use that variable to compare with the other variable to see if the time is less than.

Can you please show me an example how I can converts the time from 24 hours to 12 hours, then split the strings after the `:` to get the minute with the `AM` or `PM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the end of your last line. When you use split it is returning a list of two strings. Since you are only interested in the second (index 1) you can specify this by adding [1] after the split function.

```
converts_time = time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + str(":") + str(stop_time.split(":")[0]) + time.strftime("%p")
```

Comment: And it isn't necessary to wrap every single string with `str()`.

Comment: @JohnHoward thank you very much for this, but there is a problem. When I get the strings `22:30` it will converts to 12 hours time but the minutes will change. I don't want to get the minutes from the current time. I want to get the minutes when I split the strings to get it to join with the other strings that I converted from 24 hours to 12 hours. Please change the code.